# What condition should $\mathbf{A}$ meet for $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ to be bounded from above

Tags: linear-algebra

**Fact:**

$\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}>0 \quad \forall \quad \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ implies $\mathbf{A}$ is **sym+def**. Therefore one can do eigen value decomposition to check if $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}>0$ holds true.

Now consider following

\begin{equation}
 0<\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}<1 \quad \forall \quad \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}   \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Is there any test that I can apply on my matrix $\mathbf{A}$ so that I would know that (1) is meet.

Comment: Yes, there is such a test: no matrix $A$ satisfies (1).

Comment: If ${\bf x_1}^T A {\bf x_1} = c$ then take ${\bf x_2} = d{\bf x_1}$ to get ${\bf x_2}^T A {\bf x_2} = cd^2$. You should add some context here. Why do you need this? Are you sure you want it to hold for *all* ${\bf x}$?

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix $A$ has *any* positive eigenvalue, then $x^\top A x < 1, \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ cannot hold. (in fact, no matrix satisfies $(1)$). To see why, take some $\lambda_i > 0$ and the corresponding eigenvector $v_i$. Then

$$
v^\top A v = \lambda_i \| v \|^2 = \lambda_i > 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{t \to \infty} (tv)^\top A (tv) = \lim_{t \to \infty} t^2 \lambda_i = \infty.
$$

Comment: In my application mean squared error is $MSE=1-\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{Ax}$. Since MSE is always positive therefore $0\leq\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{Ax}\leq 1$. I dont understand why there is no such $\mathbf{A}$

Comment: In that case, you might want to add information about your application in the original post. How do you obtain such an expression for the MSE?

Comment: $\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{A}}\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$Do you know something more about $\A$ or $\x$? If $\x$ is restricted in norm for example, then there could be more to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality (1) fails for the vector $x=0$.  If you relax your condition to the weaker $x'Ax\in[0,1]$ for all vectors $x$, the condition reduces to $x'Ax=0$ for all $x$, which (it turns out) implies $A$ is skew-symmetric.  For if there existed an $x$ with $t = x'Ax>0$, then some positive multiple $ux$ of $x$ will be such that $(ux)'A(ux)=u^2t > 1$, violating the weaker constraint.